# Django tests.py django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

The question asked before but the error was having the same username in the database.

In my case database is totally empty ., here is the test case:

```
def create_django_contrib_auth_models_user(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["username"] = "adminadmin"
    defaults["email"] = "test@testus.com"
    defaults["password"] = "testpass"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return User.objects.create(**defaults)
```

when I run `python manage.py tests` i get this error as and it causes most of the other tests to fail,

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`

**update**

Here are the full `tests.py` file:

```
import unittest
from django.urls import reverse
from django.test import Client
from .models import Branch, Storage, Worker, job, Category, StorageItem, StorageMoves, Item
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


def create_django_contrib_auth_models_user(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["username"] = "adminadmin"
    defaults["email"] = "test@testus.com"
    defaults["password"] = "testpass"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return User.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_django_contrib_auth_models_group(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "group"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return Group.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_django_contrib_contenttypes_models_contenttype(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return ContentType.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_branch(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return Branch.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_storage(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    if "branch" not in defaults:
        defaults["branch"] = create_branch()
    return Storage.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_worker(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults["phone"] = "01207199086"
    defaults["address"] = "address"
    defaults["date_joined"] = "1956-01-01"
    defaults["image"] = "image"
    defaults["is_active"] = False
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    if "branch" not in defaults:
        defaults["branch"] = create_branch()
    return Worker.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_job(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return job.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_category(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    return Category.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_storageitem(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults["quantity"] = "15"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    if "storage" not in defaults:
        defaults["storage"] = create_storage()
    return StorageItem.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_storagemoves(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults["quantity"] = "15"
    defaults["text"] = "text"
    defaults["type"] = "خروج"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    if "storage" not in defaults:
        defaults["storage"] = create_storage()
    if "user" not in defaults:
        defaults["user"] = create_django_contrib_auth_models_user()
    return StorageMoves.objects.create(**defaults)


def create_item(**kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    defaults["name"] = "name"
    defaults.update(**kwargs)
    if "category" not in defaults:
        defaults["category"] = create_category()
    return Item.objects.create(**defaults)


class BranchViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for Branch
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_branch(self):
        url = reverse('erp_branch_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_branch(self):
        url = reverse('erp_branch_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_branch(self):
        branch = create_branch()
        url = reverse('erp_branch_detail', args=[branch.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_branch(self):
        branch = create_branch()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        url = reverse('erp_branch_update', args=[branch.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class StorageViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for Storage
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_storage(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storage_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_storage(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storage_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "branch": create_branch().pk,
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_storage(self):
        storage = create_storage()
        url = reverse('erp_storage_detail', args=[storage.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_storage(self):
        storage = create_storage()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "branch": create_branch().pk,
        }
        url = reverse('erp_storage_update', args=[storage.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class WorkerViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for Worker
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_worker(self):
        url = reverse('erp_worker_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_worker(self):
        url = reverse('erp_worker_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "phone": "phone",
            "address": "address",
            "date_joined": "1956-01-01",
            "image": "image",
            "is_active": "is_active",
            "branch": create_branch().pk,
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_worker(self):
        worker = create_worker()
        url = reverse('erp_worker_detail', args=[worker.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_worker(self):
        worker = create_worker()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "phone": "01207199086",
            "address": "address",
            "date_joined": "1956-01-01",
            "image": "image",
            "is_active": 'False',
            "branch": create_branch().pk,
        }
        url = reverse('erp_worker_update', args=[worker.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class jobViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for job
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_job(self):
        url = reverse('erp_job_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_job(self):
        url = reverse('erp_job_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_job(self):
        job = create_job()
        url = reverse('erp_job_detail', args=[job.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_job(self):
        job = create_job()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        url = reverse('erp_job_update', args=[job.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class CategoryViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for Category
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_category(self):
        url = reverse('erp_category_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_category(self):
        url = reverse('erp_category_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_category(self):
        category = create_category()
        url = reverse('erp_category_detail', args=[category.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_category(self):
        category = create_category()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
        }
        url = reverse('erp_category_update', args=[category.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class StorageItemViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for StorageItem
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_storageitem(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storageitem_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_storageitem(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storageitem_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "quantity": "quantity",
            "storage": create_storage().pk,
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_storageitem(self):
        storageitem = create_storageitem()
        url = reverse('erp_storageitem_detail', args=[storageitem.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_storageitem(self):
        storageitem = create_storageitem()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "quantity": "quantity",
            "storage": create_storage().pk,
        }
        url = reverse('erp_storageitem_update', args=[storageitem.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class StorageMovesViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for StorageMoves
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_storagemoves(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storagemoves_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_storagemoves(self):
        url = reverse('erp_storagemoves_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "quantity": "15",
            "text": "text",
            "type": "دخول",
            "storage": create_storage().pk,
            "user": create_django_contrib_auth_models_user().pk,
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_storagemoves(self):
        storagemoves = create_storagemoves()
        url = reverse('erp_storagemoves_detail', args=[storagemoves.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_storagemoves(self):
        storagemoves = create_storagemoves()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "quantity": "quantity",
            "text": "text",
            "type": "دخول",
            "storage": create_storage().pk,
            "user": create_django_contrib_auth_models_user().pk,
        }
        url = reverse('erp_storagemoves_update', args=[storagemoves.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class ItemViewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    Tests for Item
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_list_item(self):
        url = reverse('erp_item_list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_item(self):
        url = reverse('erp_item_create')
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "category": create_category().pk,
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_detail_item(self):
        item = create_item()
        url = reverse('erp_item_detail', args=[item.slug, ])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_update_item(self):
        item = create_item()
        data = {
            "name": "name",
            "category": create_category().pk,
        }
        url = reverse('erp_item_update', args=[item.slug, ])
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

**Settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'CHANGEME')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_extensions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
    'erp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'revo_erp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'revo_erp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'},  # noqa
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'},  # noqa
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},  # noqa
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},  # noqa
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: Can you share your settings.py and the rest of the test.py?

Comment: And btw, User.objects.create will not hash the password. You’ll need to use create_user instead

Comment: @MohamedHamza `tests.py` added to the question, tell me what part you need to check from `settings.py`?

Comment: Can u share the settings.py? Do u use the same database for testing? Try to identify the test database name inside the settings.py in the databases section. And run the command python manage.py test again and see if this works.

Comment: The databases configuration. You can identify the Test keyword inside the database to ensure that it uses a different database than the default one.

Comment: @MohamedHamza well never knew that I can control the test database, kindly check the update for the `settings.py` file

Comment: I see now. Try to identify ‘Test’: “any name” in the database section and re-run the command again

Comment: Not sure if this is how it is done, `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'Test': 'test_db',
    },
}
`  - ifyou can provide an example add as an answer

Comment: What does defaults.update(**kwargs) does exactly?

Comment: It adds the values to the dictionary labeled `defaults`. then it uses the values in the `create_user` method

Comment: You add it that way: 
``'TEST': {
       'NAME': 'auto_tests',
   }``
``DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'), 'Test': {NAME: 'test_db'} }, }``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185698/discussion-between-mohamed-hamza-and-ahmed-wagdi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is happening because you are creating the user object twice in `test_update_storagemoves`. Once by calling `create_storagemoves` and once by calling `create_django_contrib_auth_models_user`.

`create_storagemoves` calls `create_django_contrib_auth_models_user` internally, so basically you are calling `create_django_contrib_auth_models_user` twice, and basically you are creating two `User` instances with the same `username` which presumably has the `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

Answer (score 3):

Test cases should follow a certain setup as per [django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/)

to test users for example:

```
class UserTest(TestCase):
    """ Test module for GET all USERS API """


    user = None
    user2 = None

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Construct fake Users
        :return:
        """

        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="user1", superuser_status=True
                                             password="test1234")

        self.user2= User.objects.create_user(username="admin",
                                              password="123456")

    def test_get_all_users(self):
        """
        Test all users retrieval
        :return:
        """

        request = APIRequestFactory().get("/users/")
        users_list = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
        # get data from db
        users = User.objects.all()
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
        response = users_list(request)
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['results'], serializer.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```